# IIS6 Could not get the type property; JS replace dangerous char

Tags: javascript, .net

I have site for clients to login with a U/P and because the username must be an email address I've noticed through our error logs that some users accidentally paste their email in format

```
<My Name> myemail@test.com
```

into the pwd field.  I only noticed this because .NET throws an error about a potentially dangerous Request.Form due to the < in it.  I have a javascript function that can replace "<" with "< " (the space after it will not cause the error) and I'd like to apply it to the pwd - which will be incorrect anyways, but at least they will get a nice "Invalid Password" message instead of a big, ugly msg about a dangerous character.  Of course, since it's a password, I can't do a replace unless I change the type to text first.  Here's what I tried in javascript:

```
    function replaceSuspectChars(that)
{
    that.type = 'text'; 
    //Find '<' not followed by a space, and replace it with a '< '
    var text = that.value;
    text = text.replace(/</g, "< ");
    text = text.replace(/<  /g, "< ");
    that.value = text;
    that.type = 'password'; 
}
```

This worked fine on my local machine in IE, running IIS7.  But in production on IIS6 I get the error "Could not get the type property".  Is there any way to get javascript to change the textbox type, or to be able to replace the offending character in the password field, or any other way to avoid that dangerous character error?  I can't use code-behind code because the dangerous character error always displays before the post-back code is executed.

Thanks for your help.
-VG

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to allow the "<" you could set `validateRequest="false"` in the Page attribute of your .aspx page.  That should cause .net to allow the "<".  Then you wouldn't get that ugly yellow page of death, allowing you to display your nice error message.

Although for security reasons I'm not sure you would want to set validateRequest to false because that will prevent .Net from checking for script-injection attacks .  It is something to consider.

See:

1. http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/request-validation
2. [Use of setting ValidateRequest to false in ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133093/use-of-setting-validaterequest-to-false-in-asp)
3. [Asp.Net Validaterequest False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713007/asp-net-validaterequest-false)

Comment: Thank you but no, we do not want to disable the validation.  What I don't understand is this works just fine on my local machine with IIS7.  The only thing different about production is IIS6, and I don't see why it won't work there.